# Path-like tableview but with a map instead of a picture

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'd like to implement a tableview with a map as header and have the same effect than Path with the picture. 
But I want to keep the ability to interact with the map like zoom in/out, click on a pin...
Would it be possible?

I've been able to add the map view using this project [on github](https://github.com/Rheeseyb/RBParallaxTableViewController) but i'm losing userinteraction

I guess the solution would be to add an invisible mapview in the first row and pass touches events to the visible mapview which is behind the tableview?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the map view as the [tableHeaderView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/tableHeaderView) in your UITableView should be the best way.

```
MKMapView *mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 200)];
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:mapView];
```